# Routes in Rails with controllers that end in 's'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, routes

This is just cosmetic but still driving me nuts. I've created a controller for my Address object and try to lay out routes for it. However, Rails seems to interpret the last 's' as plural and removes it from my paths, like this:

routes.rb:

```
resources :address
```

(note: this line is inside a namespace block called 'admin')

When I run `rake routes` I get this:

```
new_admin_addres
edit_admin_addres
```

... and so on. How do I get the extra 's' in my paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resources :addresses`
which is the plural of address

Comment: If I use that it can't find `AddressesController`. I created the controller with `rails generate controller admin/Address`.

Comment: in fact that would be `rails g controller admin/Addresses` [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#generating-a-controller)

Comment: have you nested it inside the admin namespace? `namespace :admin { resources :addresses}`

Comment: I wiped the controller and created it with plural name. Makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Use the inflections to set address to be uncountable:
config/initializers/inflections.rb

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
   inflect.uncountable %w( address )
end
```

This should now ignore any extra 's'. Not gramatically correct but should solve the issue.

Comment: This is also useful when you are using an acronym that ends in 's'